# Split a namefile in shell

Tags: bash, shell, split, ifs

I'm here to know how to split a file name that was found by a ls comand :D. Let me explain better...

I have a variable

```
images=$( ls | grep .img )
```

And then i want to split the result of the search, because i just want the name before the .img, so a nice idea is use IFS.

`IFS=. read -r disk <<< $image`

Pretty nice, but when a do an echo with the $disk variable, what i see is a ".img" just that, i want to recover where is before that dot.

Thank you all, and sorry for any mistake :)

Comment: Suggestion: add a tag specifying *which* shell. From the discussion, it's overwhelmingly probably bash, but it's better to be explicit. Even though you've already accepted an answer, it will help future seekers with a similar problem to find that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the stream editor sed! Example:

```
echo "myImage.jpg" | sed 's/.jpg//'
```

That s means "substitute", and you substitute the part between the first two slashes for the part between the second and third slash, so in the example, ".jpg" for the empty string.

That's all!

Comment: thanks, i can't vote to the correctly answer, but you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention using `<<<`, I'll assume you are using a shell that supports arrays (specifically, `bash`. Other shells--notably `zsh`--may use different syntax for what I am about to describe).

```
images=( *.img )  # No need to parse ls, which is generally a bad idea
```

Assuming there is only one matching file, you can then use

```
disk=${images%.img}
```

to strip `.img` from the file name and save the remaining portion in `disk`. If there could be multiple matches, you can apply the extension stripping to each element of the array and store the result in a second array.

```
disks=( "${images[@]%.img}" )
```

Comment: well i coud not understand all, but it helps a lot, and my purpose is just splite the name of the files because i'm using it in a backup! 

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

`basename` is what you want.
From the man page:

```
basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames  

    EXAMPLES
           basename /usr/bin/sort
                  Output "sort".
           basename include/stdio.h .h
                  Output "stdio".
```